# Adding rows and columns in a two dimensional array in C++

Tags: c++

I am able to add the elements of a row together in C++ and want to add all elements together in all rows and columns.  What I have written out adds the the values of rows together but prints out the columns seperately.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std
int main() 
{

const int ROW = 10;
const int COL = 20;

int dimenArray[ROW][COL] ={{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, 
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}};

for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) 
{
    double totalArray = 0.0;

    for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
        {
        totalArray += dimenArray[i][j];
        }
    cout <<"The total of dimenArray is " << totalArray << "." << endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```

The output I get is.

```
The total of dimenArray is 55.
The total of dimenArray is 210.
The total of dimenArray is 0.
The total of dimenArray is 0.
The total of dimenArray is 0.
The total of dimenArray is 0.
The total of dimenArray is 0.
The total of dimenArray is 0.
The total of dimenArray is 0.
The total of dimenArray is 0.
```

I would like to add the 55 and 210 together and produce one value.  Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: If you have a matrix of integers, why do you use a `double` for the sum?

Comment: As for your problem, it seems that you want to add *all* values in `dimenArray`? So why don't you do that? Add another variable, e.g. `totalAllArray`, and then just `totalAllArray += totalArray;`.

Comment: You initialization of `int dimenArray[ROW][COL]` shows a potential misunderstanding of how a 2D array is held in memory. (while your initialization is legal), a 2D array contains `ROW` rows of `COL` values each. Your initialization initializes 1/2 the first row, then the second row -- all other values in the array are initialized zero.

Comment: Move the definition and initialisation of `totalArray` to before the loop.  Alternatively, define and initialise another variable to zero before the loop, and add the value of `totalArray` to it after the inner loop.

Comment: You're right @Someprogrammerdude I should have not used doubles for adding the float.  I'm only adding and it makes it easier.  Thank you for the tips most helpful.  I needed another variable to add it in properly.  Thanks.

Comment: @Peter spot on thanks.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I only initialized two columns just for testing purposes, you are right though about the size of array being unfilled.  Thank you for the call out on that.

Comment: @BrianMoore - that's the fly-in-the-ointment, -- you didn't initialize 2-columns, you initialized 10-values in the 1st-ROW and 20-values in the 2nd-ROW and no values in any column for rows 3-10. (row indexes 2-9)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin pardon my grammar, I was only concerned about the proper loop for grabbing and then adding into the rows, not filling them all at the moment, I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @BrianMoore oops sorry for the miscommunication. Good luck with your coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need another variable for the total across all rows.

```
double grandTotal = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) 
{
    double totalArray = 0.0;

    for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
    {
        totalArray += dimenArray[i][j];
    }
    cout <<"The total of dimenArray is " << totalArray << "." << endl;
    grandTotal += totalArray;
}
cout << "The total of all rows is " << grandTotal << "." << endl;

return 0;
```

Comment: Thank you @Barmar you were nice enough to even format it to my shoddy code.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

Move the declaration of `totalArray` outside the loop.

*Added in edit:* To wit, you wrote,

> I am able to add the elements of a row together in C++ and want to add all elements together in all rows and columns. What I have written out adds the the values of rows together but prints out the columns seperately.

Your loop is as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) 
{
    double totalArray = 0.0;

    for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
        {
        totalArray += dimenArray[i][j];
        }
    cout <<"The total of dimenArray is " << totalArray << "." << endl;
    }
```

You should rewrite it as follows:

```
double totalArray = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) 
{

    for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
        {
        totalArray += dimenArray[i][j];
        }
    cout <<"The total of dimenArray is " << totalArray << "." << endl;
    }
```

This will "add all elements", and is what I meant by "move the declaration of `totalArray` outside the loop."

Subsequent clarification by the OP makes it clear he meant something else, but that wasn't in the original question, which remains in fact unedited. So this is a correct answer to question as posted (and was before I edited, Code Review).